# Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() AND mysqlnd installed

Tags: php, mysqli

As the title suggests, I have mysqlnd available on my shared hosting server running PHP version 5.4.  When I attempt to call the mysqli get_result() function, I get this error.

I have spoken several times with the hosting provider, and most recently they told me to try running

```
# /opt/ntphp/php54/bin/php -i | grep -i mysqlnd
```

I hopped on ssh and ran this command which gave this:

```
mysqlnd
mysqlnd => enabled
Version => mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: c85105d7c6f7d70d609bb4c000257868a40840ab $
Loaded plugins => mysqlnd,example,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password
mysqlnd statistics =>  
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: c85105d7c6f7d70d609bb4c000257868a40840ab $
```

So, that appears to me as I would expect.

I found another piece of PHP code on another forum post that suggests running:

```
$hasMySQL = false; $hasMySQLi = false; $withMySQLnd = false; $sentence = '';

if (function_exists('mysql_connect')) {
    $hasMySQL = true;
    $sentence.= "(Deprecated) MySQL <b>is installed</b> "; } else
    $sentence.= "(Deprecated) MySQL <b>is not</b> installed ";

if (function_exists('mysqli_connect')) {
     $hasMySQLi = true;
     $sentence.= "and the new (improved) MySQL <b>is installed</b>. "; } else
     $sentence.= "and the new (improved) MySQL <b>is not installed</b>. ";

 if (function_exists('mysqli_get_client_stats')) {
     $withMySQLnd = true;
     $sentence.= "This server is using MySQLnd as the driver."; } else
     $sentence.= "This server is using libmysqlclient as the driver.";

 echo $sentence;
```

I did this and got the result:

> (Deprecated) MySQL is installed and the new (improved) MySQL is installed. This server is using libmysqlclient as the driver.

I'm running my hosting with Arvixe, and they had a blog post that basically said "Run PHP 5.4 and this will work".  It's clear to me that they think this function should run, but it's giving me a fatal error instead.

Side note - the code runs perfectly on my local machine, and I only get an error with the call to get_result().

EDITED:

Here is how the PHP is set up:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM User_Details WHERE LCASE(username) = LCASE(?) LIMIT 1");
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->get_result(); // This line throws the ugly error
```

Comment: I wonder if you are using a different PHP version on the CLI from the one Apache (or whatever webserver) is using.  Make a php file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it and see what version of PHP you are running and see if mysqlnd is there.  Maybe you need to edit an ini file or something to set this up properly.

Comment: PHP Version 5.4.27 and mysqlnd Version  mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: c85105d7c6f7d70d609bb4c000257868a40840ab $

Comment: Please include your test script, how are you constructing things that throws the error?

Comment: I edited to show the chunk of code that is causing the error.  It's a pretty basic script.  I suspect there is an issue with the mysqlnd on the server.  The annoying part is Arvixe keeps emailing me saying "Just switch to PHP version 5.x, then it'll work"  And it never does...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anybody wondering what's going on with this, and using Arvixe.  Here is the response I received from the staff.

> This is some confusion around MySQLND which was caused by an old
>   platform and its something I'll be communicating to my staff.
>
> We used to run a system which allowed us to have individual PHP
>   installs and at that point 5.4 and 5.5 both had MysqlND running. The
>   new PHP system we have in place runs all PHP installs on a consistent
>   config and therefore with our PHP 5.3 install (the base install) not
>   using MySQLND nor does our 5.4 or 5.5 install.
>
> This will be reviewed in future as PHP 5.6 is going to have MySQLND as
>   a default.
>
> Currently the only way we can support MySQLND is via a VPS / dedicated
>   server.

So, if you're on Arvixe and not a VPS, you're out of luck for using a super common and recommended convention for retrieving data from your database.  There are workarounds for this using a ton of different methods.  They either aren't feasible for my project or I couldn't get them to work, but for smaller queries it seems that using $stmt->bind_result() is one of the more popular methods.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

For me, I'm taking my business back to GoDaddy.  I spent over 10 hours trying to get a solution for this with no resolution offered except "We have a 60 day money back guarantee if you're not satisfied."

Thanks everyone for helping out with this.  Frustrating as it's been, I learned a lot in the process and from these boards... As is usually the case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have enabled mysqlnd with php version 5.6 in godaddy but still having this issue

Comment: @Lokesh did u get the solution for ur problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you ran the code that inspected the PHP environment was that through the webserver? I ask this because it sounds like you haven't configured your webserver to use PHP 5.4 (which allegedly has the version of mysqli you're after).

You might want to refer to [this article](http://blog.arvixe.com/change-php-version-using-the-php-version-manager/) from Arvixe.

Interestingly, it seems [the function that's causing trouble](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) is available since PHP 5.3.

You might also try a simple script to view the environment from the web

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Hit that from the web and check for a couple things

- PHP version 5.4
- mysqlnd

Personally, I'm not sure mysqlnd is required to provide the `get_results` function (but would need to dig deeper to determine that).

Another test you can do to see if in fact Arvixe's PHP 5.4 environment provides the function of interest is test the CLI environment which you know has mysqlnd

```
/opt/ntphp/php54/bin/php -r 'echo method_exists("mysqli_stmt", "get_result") . PHP_EOL;'
```

If that spits out a `1`, you almost certainly just need to follow that guide I linked to earlier to get your webserver environment running PHP 5.4.

Comment: I appreciate all the digging.  That article from Arvixe is where I began this quest.  I used that guide to change my PHP from 5.3 to 5.4 and 5.5.  My phpinfo page is showing that mysqlnd is installed, but there are no mysqlnd entries in the "configure command" section near the top, as there are on my local server.  I ran the command in ssh as you suggested and got no response, so the function is not available then?

Comment: Hmm, yeah sounds like that function may not be there; seems strange though, I expected it would be. Just to be safe, maybe try this one over ssh too - `/opt/ntphp/php54/bin/php --re mysqli | grep get_result`. If that comes back empty it's def not available.

Comment: Arvixe has me working in 5.5 now.  I ran your command as is and replaced 54 with 55 and tried again.  Both returned nothing.

Comment: I see now on that php doc I referred to mysqlnd is required (glazed over it earlier). Seems like something could be jacked with their build? Sure enough trying 2 different builds of PHP one with mysqlnd one without, and the function is only available where I have mysqlnd.

Comment: Yeah, I've gone from "I feel crazy" to "I think it has to be fixed on their end".  Not sure that's 100% accurate, but I certainly can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Yeah, I think you've done due diligence. I'd ask them to walk you through a configuration where that function is actually available. Seemingly w/ a mysqlnd build it should be there.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the existing php version and install the new version of php 5.5 or later
and verify by doing on root terminal $ php -v

Comment: Wish I could, I'm on shared not VPS so I can't run root commands.

Comment: Interestingly enough, running php -v from ssh spits out PHP 5.3.28 while looking at phpinfo.php is giving me 5.5.11 from the same directory.  Any idea what that means?

Comment: @drewkroft This is because they're supporting different versions of php on both the CLI and through the webserver. This is why they had you use `/opt/ntphp/php54/bin/php` on the CLI to explicitly say 'use PHP 5.4'. `php`, by itself is mapped to 5.3 on the CLI on their systems. Also, sounds like you're currently running 5.5 on the webserver.

Comment: I am because Arvixe just told me to move back to 5.5.  They said mysqlnd is native on 5.5 and that get_result() should be available there.

Comment: I don't believe that mysqlnd is native to 5.5 because I have a 5.5 build on my laptop without mysqlnd or mysqli::get_result. It sounds like for whatever reason, mysqlnd is not enabled on the version of PHP you're getting. I'm looking to see if there may be a runtime setting to enable that if there's more than one driver available, but haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it!  I was wondering if there was just a setting I need to check off somewhere myself, but was unable to find anything helpful with a Google search.

Comment: Had to down-vote this answer b/c the question clearly states this is a shared hosting environment in question.